# Deciphering C++ code: function in struct with same name as the struct

Tags: c++

I am trying to pick up a programming. I got this code from ai-junkie.com. I don't understand the last lines of each struct

1. SNeuron(int NumInputs),
2. SNeuronLayer(int NumNeurons, int NumInputsPerNeuron).

What is the purpose of this? Does anyone care to teach basic c++?

```
struct SNeuron {
    //the number of inputs into the neuron
    int m_NumInputs;

    //the weights for each input
    vector<double>  m_vecWeight;

    //ctor
    SNeuron(int NumInputs);
};

struct SNeuronLayer {

    //the number of neurons in this layer
    int m_NumNeurons;

    //the layer of neurons
    vector<SNeuron> m_vecNeurons;

    SNeuronLayer(int NumNeurons, int NumInputsPerNeuron);
};
```

Comment: They are both constructors: one takes one argument of type `int`, the other two. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: Moreover, the one-parameter constructor should probably be `explicit`. Don't put too much faith in random code you pick up off the street.

Comment: Thanks guys. I went through http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ but did not see the constructor declared in the struct.

Comment: I don't understand why this is put on hold as off-topic. Evidently, it was answered by @Bathsheba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a *constructor*. And someone has applied a pointless comment `ctor` to it. It allows you to instantiate an instance of `SNeuron` using code like

`SNeuron sn(5);`

This helps program stability. In C, you'd have to populate the structure fields yourself having instantiated an instance of the structure. That can leave a structure in an ill-defined state. In C++, the instance can be fully created in one step.

Remember that in C++, a `struct` is exactly the same as a `class`: with the exception that in a `struct` all member functions and member data are `public` by default (whereas in a `class` they are `private` by default).

Comment: Ahh okay - that's the difference i didn't catch. Now i understand this. Thanks! This is a great answer. I didn't understand why it's calling itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a C-tor for the `struct SNeuron` that accepts an `int`.

in C++, a `struct` is simply a `class` with all members `public` by definition. And like any `class` it can have a c-tor, d-ctor and other C++ elements.

Comment: Usually called a "ctor", in case you're going to google for it.  You really want to be getting a book on c++ if you intend to learn it, however.

Comment: @Poldie - took your note :)